# CSS for HTML in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, css, html

Is there any way to load html page to photoshop and make css for it in photoshop ? Or is there any other graphical program to make css not just by writing code ?

Comment: What you say is impossible. Even if it were possible, if HTML is not styled (that is, no CSS), Photoshop would just create blank spaces and text (at best), which doesn't make any sense at all. Are you sure you mean PS and not some other program?

Comment: It doesn't have to be photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use Photoshop like that.

What you are searching for is a **WYSIWYG editor**, and there are many.